# Is complete Srimad Bhagavatam not available since total verse count is not 18000?

Tags: scripture, vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana

Upon counting the number of verses in Bhagavatam which has 335 chapters from

http://bhagavata.org/downloads/bhagavata-compl.html

```
Canto       Chapters        Verses               

1               19            808                   
2               10            393                   
3               33           1416                  
4               31           1449                  
5               26            668                    
6               19            851                    
7               15            750                    
8               24            931                    
9               24            960                    
10              90           3936                  
11              31           1367                    
12              13            565

Total          335          14094
```

But, the sites like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavata_Purana
says the number of chapter is only 332.

I have referred one more site which says only 332 chapter, can't recollect now.

As per the following book:(foot notes in page 526)
https://archive.org/details/SriBhagavataTatparyaNirnayaEBook/page/n543

Some opine that chapter 12,13, and 14 are interpolated.

Why is count only around 14,100 where as it is supposed to be 18,000? Are the remaining 3,900 missing?

Is there any final opinion about chapter 12,13 and 14 of the 10th Canto?